# Appending chat history and insert it into the same file

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a case that I need to log the chat history (I am capable of doing this already) and I need it to be logged in a text file (able to log it already).
The problem is the file is being accessed all over again so I need to somewhere store the filename of the file somewhere else, right now I have this code:

```
public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
{
    var conversation = "";
    var convActivity = "";
    var ctr = 0;
    conversation = $"From: {activity.From.Name}\r\n  To: {activity.Recipient.Name}\r\n  Message: {activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Attachments}\r\n ";
    fileName = "test";
    await LogActivity(fileName, conversation); 
}
```

The `LogActivity` is the one handling the append of the file. So what I need is I want the unique fileName to be instantiated once while appending the file all over again or rather while continuously accessing this method.

Or is there a way to log the chat history of bot **once** like if a `Context.Done` was called or before it?

Or the inefficient way I am thinking of was making use of `.From.Name` and `.Recipient.Name`

So the result will be:

```
if (activity.From.Name.ToLower().ToString() == "user")
{
   name.Value = $"{activity.From.Name.ToString()}";
   conversation = $"From: {activity.From.Name}\r\n To: {activity.Recipient.Name}\n Message: {activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}\n";
}
else
{
   name.Value = $"{activity.Recipient.Name.ToString()}";
   conversation = $"From: {activity.From.Name}\r\n  To: {activity.Recipient.Name}\r\n  Message: {activity.AsMessageActivity()?.Text}\r\n ";
}

await LogActivity(name.Value, conversation);
```

Comment: What is the type of `activity.From.Name` if not a `string` ? Meaning, what is the use of `.ToString()` here ?

Comment: @Rafalon Well, it's actually a string. My bad, just a habit.

Comment: It's the first time I see `.ToLower().ToString()` in this order. Anyway, if I understand well, you want to log both messages of bot and user in 2 distinct files ? Where is `fileName` declared/defined in your first example ? Is the `LogActivity` method handmade or part of the framework ? If the former, please post its code :)

Comment: @Rafalon Sorry, I forgot, I have updated the code. The LogActivity is a handmade method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, **rposbo**'s answer also works if you have your own logger (that's what I observed, or maybe if you can implement it the other way around, you can use it, it's up to you) that will persist on each every conversation you have with your bot, see the link he provided on how to persist the whole conversation. As for my end, I used dictionary to store the filename. So down below is what I did

```
public string _Name { get { return name; } }
string name;

public static Dictionary<string, string> fileName = new Dictionary<string, string>();


public void SetFileName(string _fileName)
{
    var isCached = fileName.TryGetValue("filename", out name);
    if (!isCached)
    {
         name = $"{_fileName}_{DateTime.Now.Ticks}";
         fileName.Add("filename", name);
    }    
}
```

Btw, can I accept two answers? since rposbo's answer also works, but it just doesn't fit for me.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to persist a value throughout a conversation; in this case a filename.

If that's correct, then you can store it in `PrivateConversationData` which lives in the`context`.

For example:

`context.PrivateConversationData.SetValue<string>("log_filename", "log-name-here.txt");`

For an example, check here: https://www.robinosborne.co.uk/2016/08/08/persisting-data-within-a-conversation-with-botframeworks-dialogs/

For a full example about persisting the whole conversation, this might also help: https://www.robinosborne.co.uk/2016/11/22/transcribing-messages-in-botframework/

Comment: I'll try this, thanks, so does this work like a session?

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, the only downside of this, is that I need to create my own logger service in order for me to bypass the `IActivityLogger` because `IActivityLogger` will initiate a `UserToBot` at the very first time and I wouldn't be able to use this method as it would continue to my `LogAsync` rather than calling the `Dialog` first inheriting `IDialog` or `Luis` and that's my problem.  
In summary, User will first send a message and will go through the class inheriting `IActivityLogger` and not the `Dialog` itself first.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the downside here. You should be able to use the indicated solution from the your IActivityLogger implementation

Comment: The `IActivityLogger` implements `LogAsync` who only accepts `IActivity` in this case, I cannot pass context as it is, and use the `PrivateConversationData` persistent method of `context`. Because right now, the initial message of the user goes through `LogAsync` first before anything else.